# How to properly call groovy gradle method from kotlin dsl

Tags: android, groovy, android-gradle-plugin, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I have separate groovy script that adds flavors to my android project. And i can apply it no problem in build.gradle files. But calling it from  kotlin build.gradle.kts file im getting error.

I have `flavors.gradle` file

```
ext.configFlavors = {
    flavorDimensions "brand"
    productFlavors {
        myBrand {
            dimension "brand"
        }
}
```

And i can easilly call this from build.gradle files

```
android{
...
with configFlavors

}
```

But in build.gradle.kts files i get:

```
Could not find method flavorDimensions() for arguments [brand] on project ': myModule' of type org.gradle.api.Project.
```

My build.gradle.kts looks like this:

```
import com.android.build.gradle.LibraryExtension

plugins {
    id("com.android.library")
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android")
}
apply(from ="${rootProject.projectDir}/buildSrc/flavors.gradle" )

val configFlavors: groovy.lang.Closure<LibraryExtension> by extra
android {
    compileSdk = Versions.compile_sdk_version

    defaultConfig {
        minSdk = Versions.min_sdk_version
        targetSdk = Versions.target_sdk_version

        testInstrumentationRunner = "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        consumerProguardFiles("consumer-rules.pro")
    }

    buildTypes {
        //Dev
        create("dev") {
            isMinifyEnabled = false
            proguardFiles(getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro")
        }

        //Staging
        create("staging") {
            isMinifyEnabled = false
            proguardFiles(getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro")
        }

        //Production
        create("production") {
            isMinifyEnabled = false
            proguardFiles(getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro")
        }
    }
// I am able to call the closure but i got the error
    configFlavors()
    
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding = true
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation(fileTree("include" to listOf("*.jar"), "dir" to "libs"))
    implementation(project(":domain"))
//    list of dependencies

}
```

Comment: What code did you write in your `build.gradle.kts`? What are the class/interface definitions of `configFlavours` and `productFlavors`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up adding another closure that takes libraryExtension as parameter. And using it from gradle.build.kts files. It is not optimal but it seems to work.

```
ext.configFlavorsWithParam = { libraryExtension ->
    libraryExtension.flavorDimensions "brand"
    libraryExtension.productFlavors {
        brand1 {
            dimension "brand"
        }
}
```

And im calling it like this

```
android{
...
configFlavorsWithParam(this)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Extra properties can be accessed with the following syntax:

```kotlin
// get an extra property from the current project
val myProperty: String by extra 


// or from the root project
val myNewProperty: String by rootProject.extra
```

However, `configFlavours` is not a simple primitive value, it's a [Closure](https://groovy-lang.org/closures.html).

It's [possible to access Closures in Kotlin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/kotlin_dsl.html#groovy_closures_from_kotlin), but without knowing what type the Closure should apply to, it's not possible to use it.

```
// Replace `Any` with the actual type, if known
val configFlavours: groovy.lang.Closure<Any> by extra

println(configFlavours)
// > Configure project :
// flavours_atn69ibjqzvnwf0cp7hb75l45$_run_closure1@398b577e
```

[There are more through examples in the Gradle docs](https://docs.gradle.org/7.6/userguide/kotlin_dsl.html#extra_properties)

---

P.S. your code has both `flavour` and `flavor` - pick a spelling please :)

Comment: I edited  with my gradle.build.kts file. I am using the syntax you show to call the closure, but i am getting error that `flavorDimensions` canot be find on type `org.gradle.api.Project` . But i need to call the closure on type `LibraryExtension` as it has this method.